# Enabling Template Inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance, django-templates

Python 2.7.1 / Django 1.3

I am new to Django Templates and trying to do very simple template inheritance.

## testbase.html

```
hello

{% block tester %}
fail
{% endblock %}
```

## testblock.html

```
{% extends "testbase.html" %}

{% block tester %}
pass
{% endblock %}
```

## result

```
hello fail
```

The two templates are in the same directory which has been added to the project settings.py file and since it finds the base template I'm having trouble finding why it wouldn't be able to find the child template.

Thanks for any ideas on what to try next.

Comment: Are you rendering "testblock.html" from your view?

Comment: yes, it is being rendered from a view and I suspect the view renders the base template properly because it renders "hello fail".  Seems to be a disconnect between the base view and the one containing the block.

Comment: could you please show your view (at least part of it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you need to make sure the template you are pointing to is `testblock.html` and not `testbase.html`.

Assuming you're using `render_to_response`, it would look something like:

```
return render_to_response('testblock.html')
```

If your view function is referencing `testbase.html`, then you'll get the unextended template. That's by design.

Here's a link to the [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/) for good measure. :)

Comment: Thanks!  I was calling the base template from the view.  Got too caught up in thinking it was a problem in the templates.